# Sensor supply current?

Tags: sensor, power-supply, current, datasheet

I'm reading a datasheet for an accelerometer (specifically [this](http://www.bosch-sensortec.com/content/language1/downloads/BMA145_DataSheet_Rev.1.1_02APR2008.pdf)) and it lists the max supply current as 290 uA. Does this mean that the power supply I use should never output more than 290 uA? Or does this just mean the device only consumes 290 uA max? In standby mode, the max supply current decreases. Does this mean I have to dynamically reduce the output current from the power supply?

Answer (score 10):

You seem to be suffering from a fairly common misconception about current. Typical power supplies do not *push* current into loads. Instead, they provide a constant voltage. Under a given voltage, an intrinsic property of the device (AKA resistance or impedance) determines how much current will flow. In other words, the supply sets the voltage, and the device decides what the current will be.

In your case, the data sheet tells you the device will need 290 uA, presumably at some voltage which you didn't mention. This means your supply needs to be *capable* of at least that much current. Extra capability in the supply doesn't hurt the device, in fact, it's desirable, because when a device tries to draw more current than a supply is capable of, undesirable things happen. Better supplies will reduce their output voltage to keep the current down to what they can handle, but lower voltage may make the device operate erratically, or not at all. In a cheaper supply, you'll pop a fuse. Very poorly designed supplies may even burn out.

Answer (score 4):

No.Yes.No. If it was opposite, then there would be 10 extra pages in datasheet with description of power supply and manufacturer would never be able to sell a single device.

The only power critical device (voltage wise) I know is laser diode

Comment: What's the max current I reasonably put out from power supply? I've been using 400 mA before I started worrying about supply current.

Comment: The specced current is exceeded ? And voltage is ok. then blame extra current on outside load. Your chip is spending some extra current on communication. And it is normally expected by design. This extra current is not counted into specs. I read your datasheet btw.